# Find and Replace Shell Commands

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, ssh, putty

I have a wordpress installation that is infected..
Mostly theme files and plugin files..

I need 3 commands and i will be using putty:

1- inside root and recursive sub-directories folders change all 200 permissions to 644 (for some reason every time i change this manually it come back to 200 after a minute)

2- inside root and recursive sub-directories folders to replace content of index.php

with:

3- delete all php.ini files inside root and recursive sub-directories folders.

Comment: The permissions being reset mean you have a major problem; you will need to get a handle on which process is doing that (is it a `cron` job, or something being forked regularly) and kill it and ensure it stays killed?  You may need an expert to help you on site...where is your system?  Do you have physical access?  Do you have a recent backup of the site?

Comment: not cron- It was inside wp-upload.. 
http://www.hotforsecurity.com/blog/thousands-of-wordpress-sites-compromised-through-mailpoet-vulnerability-9723.html

Answer (score 3):

0 Backup!

1 If permission change every minute, probably you have a script that run every minute... in any case

```
 find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; // for directories
 find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; // for files
```

2 You have to use sed or somethings similar, according to string to replace.

3

```
 find . -iname "php.ini" -exec rm -fv {} \;
```

4 Call an expert and find how your wordpress installation has been hacked.

Comment: cannot be backed up because 200 permission locks all files containing  malwares.

Comment: Run the find commands above and than move your entire vhost path, like `mv vhosts/yoursite vhosts/yousite.hacked`. Now you can fix your installation and revert mv command.